# How do I make Quartz Scheduler to run every hour not to run if the previous hour's job is not yet completed?

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I did setup a Cron Job that runs every hour in C# as a service; it sweeps files from a folder and dumps them onto ftp, however during busy hours one hour is not enough, how do we make sure that the previous hours job is completed first before starting this hours job.

Answer (score 2):

There's an attribute called `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` which you can use. Refer to the documentation pertaining to the exact version of Quartz Scheduler.NET that you are using.

You can find more info about it at https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html